# Node.js RESTAPI REsponse waiting before executing next steps

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I am working on Amazon Lex.  In Amazon Lambda I wrote a Node.js function which invoke an Openweather API call.  Here is the function.

```
function todaysweather(intentRequest, callback, data) {
    const location = intentRequest.currentIntent.slots.location;
    const source = intentRequest.invocationSource;
  const outputSessionAttributes = intentRequest.sessionAttributes || {};
  const temp = JSON.parse(outputSessionAttributes.temp || '{}');
  ***console.log("Inside perform request");***
  var endpoint = '/data/2.5/weather?q=${location}&appid=234426bef0d81ef4474073344f';
  var method = 'POST';
  var dataString = JSON.stringify(data);
  var headers = {};
  var responseObject;

  if (method == 'GET') {
    endpoint += '?' + querystring.stringify(data);
  }
  else {
    headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Content-Length': dataString.length
    };
  }
  var options = {
    host: host,
    path: endpoint,
    method: method,
    headers: headers
  };
  ***console.log("Before http perform request");***
  var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf-8');
    var responseString = '';
    res.on('data', function(data) {
      responseString += data;
    });
  ***console.log("before perform response");***
    res.on('end', function() {
      console.log(responseString);
      responseObject = JSON.parse(responseString);
      var tempVAR = responseObject.main.temp;
      console.log("*************" + tempVAR);
      //success(responseObject);
    });
  });

  req.write(dataString);
  req.end();

  ***console.log("before callback request");***
    callback(close(outputSessionAttributes, 'Fulfilled', { contentType: 'PlainText',
       content: `Okay, I have booked your appointment.  We will see you` }));
}
```

The API call is taking few millisecond to respond back... before that my next code is getting exectute.... How to stop it from execution.  if you look at the logs below  "before callback request" is getting executed before "before response request "    Help me on how to resolve this ?????

>  09:32:13 START RequestId: 6fafb856-8ef8-11e7-8a17-afa62db3dcdc
>   Version: $LATEST  09:32:13
>   2017-09-01T09:32:13.734Z  6fafb856-8ef8-11e7-8a17-afa62db3dcdc    event.bot.name=TodaysWeather
>    09:32:13
>   2017-09-01T09:32:13.735Z  6fafb856-8ef8-11e7-8a17-afa62db3dcdc    dispatch
>   userId=yczl74p0he593v0kduouy5c5nhci50e5, intentName=Todaysweather 
>   09:32:13
>   2017-09-01T09:32:13.735Z  6fafb856-8ef8-11e7-8a17-afa62db3dcdc    **Inside
>   perform request**  09:32:13
>   2017-09-01T09:32:13.735Z  6fafb856-8ef8-11e7-8a17-afa62db3dcdc    **Before
>   http perform request**  09:32:13
>   2017-09-01T09:32:13.975Z  6fafb856-8ef8-11e7-8a17-afa62db3dcdc    **before
>   callback request**  09:32:14
>   2017-09-01T09:32:14.190Z  6fafb856-8ef8-11e7-8a17-afa62db3dcdc    **before
>   response request**  09:32:14
>   2017-09-01T09:32:14.193Z  6fafb856-8ef8-11e7-8a17-afa62db3dcdc    {"coord":{"lon":-71.32,"lat":44.63},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast
>   clouds","icon":"04n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":280.34,"pressure":1015,"humidity":70,"temp_min":279.15,"temp_max":281.15},"visibility":16093,"wind":{"speed":2.6,"deg":250},"clouds":{"all":90},"dt":1504257840,"sys":{"type":1,"id":1956
>    09:32:14
>   2017-09-01T09:32:14.233Z  6fafb856-8ef8-11e7-8a17-afa62db3dcdc    *************280.34
>    09:32:14 END RequestId: 6fafb856-8ef8-11e7-8a17-afa62db3dcdc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is because of the Node.js asynchronous nature. You're sending the request, and calling the callback after that, without waiting for the response to come.

To wait for response, you need to *call the lambda callback in the callback of `res.on('end',..`.* Something like:

```
res.on('end', function() {
  responseObject = JSON.parse(responseString);
  callback(close(outputSessionAttributes, 'Fulfilled', { contentType: 'PlainText', content: `Okay, I have booked your appointment.  We will see you` }));
});
```

In this case, you will call the lambda callback only when you finish receiing the response from the API.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you King.. solution is helpful

Comment: @user3083804 Do accept the answer, if it solves your query.